# HAProxy allow all suffix

Tags: proxy, reverse, haproxy, proxmox

I installed a Server with Proxmox and some lxc container. On this server several domains should run with only one public IP. Currently I'm trying to realize a reverse proxy with HAProxy, but it doesn't allow subfolders or variables.

For example this access is not possible: 
domain.tld/css/default.css
domain.tld/system/login

How can I allow all connections?

My Config:

```
frontend http_in
    mode tcp
    bind *:80
    bind *:443

    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    acl sslv3 req.ssl_ver 3
    tcp-request content reject if sslv3
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }

    acl web1 hdr(host) -i domain1.tld

    acl web2 hdr(host) -i domain2.tld

    use_backend web1 if web1
    use_backend web2 if web2

backend web1
        mode tcp
        server web1 10.10.10.110

backend web2
        mode tcp
        server web2 10.10.10.112
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What about it isn't working? The requests are routing properly? Could you share an example of what isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

According to this link:

https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/tcp-with-acl-possible/283/2

You should set mode to http (not tcp) on the frontend in order to make hdr(host) ACL work. I am using a similar config without any problem with mode set to http.

There should not be any problem about paths (suffixes) once the proxy operation works correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. With this configuration HA Proxy won't start. I set frontend on http mode and the backend on tcp mode. the default mode is tcp.

Comment: Yes, also tried. Front and Backend in http mode and I have the same problem. Proxy starts, but the website don't load any css or images and so on

Comment: An addition to my configs: The host with proxmox has this in the iptables and route all connection over port 80 and 443 to the guest with haproxy

post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.100:80
post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.100:80
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.100:443
post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.100:443

Comment: You are getting a 404 message from an apache server, which means that your request reaches the backend. Do the css, img etc. load on local ip? like http://10.10.10.110/css/style.css

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a apache config problem: Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All......

Answer (score 0):

```
haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-12-12 14:03:06 UTC; 6s ago
     Docs: man:haproxy(1)
           file:/usr/share/doc/haproxy/configuration.txt.gz
  Process: 4294 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -f $CONFIG -p $PIDFILE $EXTRAOPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4322 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/haproxy -f $CONFIG -c -q $EXTRAOPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4294 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy haproxy[4320]: [ALERT] 345/140306 (4320) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy haproxy[4321]: [ALERT] 345/140306 (4321) : http frontend 'http_in' (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:41) tries to use incompatible tcp backend 'web1' (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:61) in a 'use_backend' rule (see 'mode').
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy haproxy[4321]: [ALERT] 345/140306 (4321) : http frontend 'http_in' (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:41) tries to use incompatible tcp backend 'web2' (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:65) in a 'use_backend' rule (see 'mode').
 Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy haproxy[4321]: [ALERT] 345/140306 (4321) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy haproxy[4322]: [ALERT] 345/140306 (4322) : http frontend 'http_in' (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:41) tries to use incompatible tcp backend 'web1' (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:61) in a 'use_backend' rule (see 'mode').
Dec 12 14:03:06 haproxy haproxy[4322]: [ALERT] 345/140306 (4322) : http frontend 'http_in' (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:41) tries to use incompatible tcp backend 'web2' (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:65) in a 'use_backend' rule (see 'mode').
```

Do I understand something wrong?

Comment: I don't believe you can route http frontend requests to a tcp backend was the error message notes.